# PHP - Utilizando senhas com phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer, envio-de-email

Trabalhando com php mailer, surgiu uma dúvida referente ao uso de senhas.
Estou desenvolvendo uma página com formulário, e queria saber se é seguro colocar a senha do email na própria classe email, ou enviar a senha a partir da página do formulário por meio do método construtor, ou devo criar um arquivo .ini com as credenciais.

Classe email:

```
<?php

class Email
{

    private $mailer;

    public function __construct($host,$username,$senha,$name)
    {

        $this->mailer = new PHPMailer;
        
        $this->mailer->isSMTP();  // telling the class to use SMTP
        $this->mailer->SMTPAuth   = true; // SMTP authentication
        $this->mailer->Host       = $host; // SMTP server
        $this->mailer->Port       = 465; // SMTP Port
        $this->mailer->SMTPSecure       = 'ssl'; 
        $this->mailer->Username   = $username; // SMTP account username
        $this->mailer->Password   = $senha;       // SMTP account password
        
        $this->mailer->SetFrom($username, $name); // FROM
        $this->mailer->isHTML = (true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É parcialmente seguro, só existe uma possibilidade da senha vazar em scripts PHP, é se algum debug que mostra o source estiver ligado, mas isso não seria falha de ter colocado a senha na classe e sim de ter deixado o debug ligado, como por exemplo se o XDebug estiver ligado no seu servidor (já encontrei muitos servidores com isso ligado):

[image: variaveis expostas]

Veja que nesse exemplo (em um wordpress) aonde ocorreu a falha as variaveis no escopo foram expostas.

Em certos frameworks também tem sistema de debug proprio, se o debug estiver ligado irá em caso de erro irá emitir algo como:

[image: Laravel 8]

Veja que parte do código é exposto.

Note que isso não é culpa do XDebug e nem dos frameworks, porque em produção (no seu servidor) nada disso deve estar ligado, nunca. O modo debug deve ser usado somente em ambiente de desenvolvimento e eventualmente em "homologação".

Em resumo duas condições são necessárias para expor algo do código, seja senha ou o código em si:

- Modo debug ligado (seja lá qual for)
- Ter um erro no script

Fora isso é improvavel que a senha venha a ser exposta, ainda sim colocar a senha no meio do código pode ser complicado de dar manutenção, já que precisará editar o código acaso a senha mude, portanto isolar configurações em outros arquivos pode facilitar, não precisa ser um .ini, pode ser um .php assim:

```
<?php
return [
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'smtp_server' => 'smtp.foo.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => 'foo@foo.com',
    'smtp_pass' => 'teste',
];
```

E com o return ao fazer um `require ...;` no seu script você terá:

```
    $this->mailer = new PHPMailer;

    $configs = require 'config/smtp.php';
    
    $this->mailer->isSMTP();  // telling the class to use SMTP
    $this->mailer->SMTPAuth   = true; // SMTP authentication
    $this->mailer->Host       = $configs['smtp_server']; // SMTP server
    $this->mailer->Port       = $configs['smtp_port']; // SMTP Port
    $this->mailer->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $this->mailer->Username   = $configs['smtp_user']; // SMTP account username
    $this->mailer->Password   = $configs['smtp_pass']; // SMTP account password
```

---

Agora vou falar algo sobre o seu código em geral, não vejo sentido em criar outra classe só para colocar uma classe dentro, OOP não foi criado para deixar as coisas mais bonitas, foi criado para ser usado quando necessário, o `new PHPMailer` já é uma classe, criar outra só para jogar tudo dentro não necessariamente tornará as coisas mais simples, seria mais fácil criar apenas uma função básica:

```
function send_mail($destinatario, $assunto, $conteudo)
{
    $mailer = new PHPMailer;

    $configs = require 'config/smtp.php';
    
    $mailer->isSMTP();  // telling the class to use SMTP
    $mailer->SMTPAuth   = true; // SMTP authentication
    $mailer->Host       = $configs['smtp_server']; // SMTP server
    $mailer->Port       = $configs['smtp_port']; // SMTP Port
    $mailer->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mailer->Username   = $configs['smtp_user']; // SMTP account username
    $mailer->Password   = $configs['smtp_pass']; // SMTP account password
    
    $mailer->SetFrom($username, $name); // FROM
    $mail->addAddress($destinatario);
    $mailer->isHTML = $conteudo;

    return $mailer;
}
```